# Jquery to hide button when there are no more images on the right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im trying to write a HTML CSS JQUERY program where when I click "next" it will display the next images and when i click "prev" it will display the previous images and to hide the next button if there are no more images on the right and vise versa
im trying to write a HTML CSS JQUERY program where when I click "next" it will display the next images and when i click "prev" it will display the previous images and to hide the next button if there are no more images on the right and vise versa

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();

    if (nextImg.length) {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      a = nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
      console.log(nextImg.length)
      if (!(nextImg.length)) {

        next.style.displsy = "none";
      }
    }
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

    if (prevImg.length) {
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
    }

    currentImage = $(".active");
    if (!currentImg.next().length) {
      $(".next").hide;
    } else {
      $(".next").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}

.slider-inner img {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.slider-inner img.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prev,
.next {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.prev {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 540px;
  height: 40px auto;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-outer">
    <button class="prev" id="prev">Prev</button>
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" class="active" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    </div>
    <button class="next" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please capitalize and punctuate your sentences properly so we can understand you better. Also, "im" isn't a word in English.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the problems are:

- A spelling mistake in `displsy = "none"`
- Missing parentheses in `$(".next").hide`
- When clicking "next", the "prev" button should appear again (if it was hidden), and vice versa.

You should also avoid code repetition, so create a function that gets as argument whether it should call `.next()` or `.prev()` and then do all the common things. Also, `.toggle` is a nice jQuery function so you can avoid an `if..else`:

```js
function rotate(direction) {
  var currentImg = $('.active');
  currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
  currentImg = currentImg[direction]();
  currentImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);

  $(".next").toggle(currentImg.next().length > 0);
  $(".prev").toggle(currentImg.prev().length > 0);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').on('click', () => rotate("next"));
  $('.prev').on('click', () => rotate("prev"));
});
```

```css
.slider-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
}

.slider-inner img {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.slider-inner img.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prev,
.next {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.prev {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.next {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -45px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 540px;
  height: 40px auto;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider-outer">
    <button class="prev" id="prev">Prev</button>
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500?text=1" class="active" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500?text=2" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500?text=3" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500?text=4" />
    </div>
    <button class="next" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```